# How to compare two point estimates between two samples

Tags: distributions, bootstrap, entropy

I have two samples, composed by independent observations and a set of features. Each sample can be represented as a binary matrix ($A_{ij} \in \{0, 1\}$) of observations x features. I want to find differences in [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) for each feature between the two samples, i.e. which features have differences and which are the most different (one sample vs the other).

My idea is to use bootstrapping to compute an empirical distribution of entropy for each feature, for each sample. Then for each feature compare the two empirical distributions of entropy (one sample vs the other) with Kolmogorov-Smirnov test.

Finally, I want to sort the features using the difference in entropy between the two samples.

Is this procedure statistically sound? Are there issues or caveats I need to consider?